# Strange Fontello Icon Font Behaviour

Tags: html, css, apache, fontello

Am on Linux/Apache with Godaddy

I've created the following identical file on 2 different locations http://cdn.soko360.com/ and http://soko360.com/. On the first host, the font shows correctly, on the second it doesn't (no matter what I do!). The files hook Fontello via `<link href="/fonts/fontello-24px/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`. The exact same folder copied across.

Try for yourself here

http://cdn.soko360.com/demo2.php (working)

http://soko360.com/demo2.php (not working)

The 2 hosts are actually the very same one host, am only using virtual hosting.
The .htaccess files are identical. The permissions are identical.

What on earth is the problem? It's so frustrating!!!!

Comment: Please look in the browser error console: *Font from origin 'http://cdn.soko360.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://soko360.com' is therefore not allowed access.*

Comment: if you'd bothered to check your browser's debug console: "bad URI or cross-site access not allowed"

Comment: Bless you Marc! You're quite right. I'll sort that at once.

Comment: I think it would be good to share your solution. You can answer your question, no problem :)